# Do svn hooks read vbs, ruby, ... scripts because of .NET?

Tags: .net, svn, version-control, vbscript, svn-hooks

I'm new to the .NET world, and I would like to make my understanding clear.

Is the reason to why SVN hooks are able to read Ruby or Visual Basic scripts and more, because  the hooks are compiled under the .NET Framework?

Thank you

Comment: I found this interesting article about the hooks:
http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/02/creating-subversion-pre-commit-hooks-in.html

he says they are partly written in Unix, but the author writes his hooks under .NET

But I'm not sure what he means by writing under .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html), every executable can be used for a hook:

> On Unix platforms, this means supplying a script or program (which
>   could be a shell script, a Python program, a compiled C binary, or any
>   number of other things) named exactly like the name of the hook. Of
>   course, the template files are present for more than just
>   informational purposes—the easiest way to install a hook on Unix
>   platforms is to simply copy the appropriate template file to a new
>   file that lacks the .tmpl extension, customize the hook's contents,
>   and ensure that the script is executable. Windows, however, uses file
>   extensions to determine whether or not a program is executable, so you
>   would need to supply a program whose basename is the name of the hook,
>   and whose extension is one of the special extensions recognized by
>   Windows for executable programs, such as .exe or .com for programs,
>   and .bat for batch files.

So the short answers is: No.